# Translate Text for Wordpress Admin Menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to modify the text for the Wordpress Admin Menu.

I have created a case statment, which allows me to translate the text, but I am having trouble finding the hook that I can use for the admin menu.

Here is a snippet for some of the translations I have already made.

```
switch ( $translated_text ) {

            case '%1$s #%2$s details' :
                $translated_text = __( $this->get_order_title() . 'Record #%2$s', 'woocommerce' );
                break;
            case 'Product' :
                $translated_text = __( 'Activity', 'woocommerce' );
                break;
            case '%s actions' :
                $translated_text = __( 'Actions', 'woocommerce' );
                break;
            case 'Order date:' :
                $translated_text = __( 'Date created', 'woocommerce' );
                break;
            case 'Customer details' :
                $translated_text = __( 'Participant details', 'woocommerce-bookings' );
                break;
            case 'Edit order' :
                $translated_text = __( 'Record Details', 'woocommerce' );
                break;
            case 'Order updated.' :
                $translated_text = __( 'Record updated.', 'woocommerce' );
                break;
            case 'Order status:' :
                $translated_text = __( 'Status', 'woocommerce' );
                break;
            case 'Product Data' :
                $translated_text = __( 'Opportunity Data', 'woocommerce' );
                break;
```

It would be great to find out what I can use as the hook for the admin menu.

Thanks for any help or suggestions ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter `gettext` like this:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'translate_text_custom_1982212981', 20, 3 );
function translate_text_custom_1982212981( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {

        switch ( $translated_text ) {

            case '%1$s #%2$s details' :
                $translated_text = __( $this->get_order_title() . 'Record #%2$s', 'woocommerce' );
                break;
            case 'Product' :
                $translated_text = __( 'Activity', 'woocommerce' );
                break;
            case '%s actions' :
                $translated_text = __( 'Actions', 'woocommerce' );
                break;
            case 'Order date:' :
                $translated_text = __( 'Date created', 'woocommerce' );
                break;
            case 'Customer details' :
                $translated_text = __( 'Participant details', 'woocommerce-bookings' );
                break;
            case 'Edit order' :
                $translated_text = __( 'Record Details', 'woocommerce' );
                break;
            case 'Order updated.' :
                $translated_text = __( 'Record updated.', 'woocommerce' );
                break;
            case 'Order status:' :
                $translated_text = __( 'Status', 'woocommerce' );
                break;
            case 'Product Data' :
                $translated_text = __( 'Opportunity Data', 'woocommerce' );
                break;
        }
    return $translated_text;
}
```